# Sum consecutive strings in multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a table with flight ids, arrivals, and departures:

```
> test
   arrival departure flight_id
1                  9      2233
2                  8      1982
3        1                2164
4                  9      2081
5                         2130
6        2                2040
7        9                2030
8                         2130
9                  4      3169
10       6                2323
11                 8      2130
12                        2220
13                        3169
14                 9      2204
15       1                1910
16                 2       837
17                        1994
18       9         8      1994
19                        1994
20                        1994
21       9         1      2338
22       1         8      1981
23       9                2365
24                 8      2231
25       9                2048
```

My objective is to count only the rows where arrival and departure are blank, and then to aggregate by `flight_id`. But there is a catch. I believe this cannot be done with `table()`, `aggregate()` or `rle()` because they do not account for breaks.

For example, only  *consecutive*  flight ids where arrival ="" and departure ="" should be counted, and the count should start again from zero if a flight id with a non-blank value occurs.  **NOTE:** Other flight ids appearing in between don't matter - each flight id should be treated separately which is why flight 2130 is counted twice.

In other words, the resulting output from the `test` should look exactly like this:

```
output
  flight_id count
1      2130     2
2      2220     1
3      3169     1
4      1994     1
5      1994     2
```

Notice that flight id 1994 occurs three times where arrival and departure are blank but that there is a break in between at row 18.  Therefore, the flight id must be counted twice.

I have tried writing a for loop but get an error that  there is `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`:

```
raw_data = test
unique_id = unique(raw_data$flight_id)

output<- data.frame("flight_id"= integer(0), "count" = integer(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (flight_id in unique_id)
{
  oneflight <- raw_data[ which(raw_data$flight_id == flight_id), ]

  if(nrow(oneflight) >= 1 ){
    for(i in 2:nrow(oneflight)) {
      if(oneflight[i,"arrival"] == "" & oneflight[i,"departure"] == "") {
        new_row <- c(flight_id, sum(flight_id)[i])
        output[nrow(output) + 1,] = new_row
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How could one improve the above code or could someone suggest a quicker method with `dplyr` for example?  Here is a sample of the data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(arrival = c("", "", "1", "", "", "2", "9", "", 
"", "6", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "", "9", "", "", "9", "1", 
"9", "", "9"), departure = c("9", "8", "", "9", "", "", "", "", 
"4", "", "8", "", "", "9", "", "2", "", "8", "", "", "1", "8", 
"", "8", ""), flight_id = c(2233, 1982, 2164, 2081, 2130, 2040, 
2030, 2130, 3169, 2323, 2130, 2220, 3169, 2204, 1910, 837, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 2338, 1981, 2365, 2231, 2048)), .Names = c("arrival", 
"departure", "flight_id"), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Flight `2130` is empty at row 5 and 8 why is it considered as one ?

Comment: Because in between row 5 and row 8, flight `2130` had no occurrences of non-blank arrival and departure.  A break is relative to individual `flight_id`s, if that makes sense.  In other words, other flight ids should not be considered when considering one flight id - they should be extracted one by one (which is why I thought a for loop was the right way to go about it) and kept in the order in which they appear in the data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I added a note to the question.

Comment: `test %>% group_by(flight_id) %>% mutate(i = data.table::rleid(arrival, departure)) %>% filter(arrival == '', departure == '') %>% count(i)` maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach :

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(test, test$flight_id), function(x) {
   o = rle(x[["arrival"]] == "" & x[["departure"]] == "")
  data.frame(flight_id = rep(unique(x[["flight_id"]]), sum(o$values)), 
             count = o$lengths[o$values])
}))

#flight_id count
#  1994     1
#  1994     2
#  2130     2
#  2220     1
#  3169     1
```

We split the dataframe by `flight_id` and for every group we apply `rle` to find continuous empty rows in `arrival` and `departure` and return a dataframe with the `flight_id` and the number of continuous empty rows in the group.

Comment: `data.table` is always going to be faster, I agree. However, there are people (like me) who prefer `base R` and in case the data is not that huge to worry about efficiency. This is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, one trick you could use is to add a decimale to the flight_id, indicating a group.

For example, get an index vector

```
 i <- find(oneflight$arrival == "" & oneflight$departure =="")
```

Then take cumsum(1-diff(i)) / 100 or a sufficiently large power of ten, add it to the flight IDs, and you then have groups flights that can be counted with table()

Comment: That makes sense. Could you provide the solution by integrating it into the already existing code?  Where would you insert it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
flights <- test$flight_id[test$arrival=="" & test$departure==""]

setDT(test)[flight_id %in% flights, grp := rleid(arrival=="",departure=="")][
    arrival=="" & departure=="",.(count = .N),.(flight_id, grp)]
#   flight_id grp count
#1:      2130   1     2
#2:      2220   3     1
#3:      3169   3     1
#4:      1994   3     1
#5:      1994   5     2
```

**Explanation:**

First we attain the `flight_id`'s that have at least one record with empty `arrival` and `departure` values. Then, we use this vector `flights` to subset your data and generate a run-length id column based on `arrival==""` and `departure ==""` called `"grp"`. Lastly we generate the count of of records (ie. `.N`) where, `arrival=="" & departure ==""`, grouped by the columns `flight_id` and `grp`.

You can consequently drop the `grp` column if needed.

Comment: Thanks, how should I understand the values in the `grp` column? - 1, 3, and 5?

Comment: First, look at `setDT(test)[flight_id %in% flights,]`. If we add `grp:=rleid(arrival=="" & departure =="")` here, it will be a run length id column that increases every time the `departure` and `arrival` columns switch from empty to non-empty. We only generate this column to be able to group your records in the next step.

Comment: On a larger dataset this is not producing the correct output in the `count` column, but I'm not sure where the issue is.  It might be that I did not explain well enough - I marked the correct solution above.

Comment: Or it might be that you did not provide a representative example.